# Image crop for touch devices

Tags: 7, media

I am using imagecrop module for imagecrop field. but it is not working in touch deveices like ( ipad ). There is any best module for image crop in touch devices?. please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the [SimpleCrop module](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplecrop), hope it fits your needs.

> SimpleCrop provides the simplest workflow for manual crop of images. Basically, you can crop image in three steps: upload image => select area => save content. Functionality of this module covers more than 90% needs of manual image crops.
>
> One of the key feature of this module is that this crop can be used as-is for the end users. So you don't need to theme or to add a workarounds to show this image crop to someone else. It has minimalistic and usable UI.

Comment: Did you got this solution working?